# Passing Parameters from one stored procedure to another

Tags: sql-server

i have 3 stored proc A,B,C A,
the application call A  with the all parameters  then A call B and C

```
ex 
--------------------------------------------
CREATE PROC B
 @b int
  as 
   begin tran
    do something  
   commit 
-------------------------------------------    
CREATE PROC C
 @c varchar(50)
  as 
   begin tran
    do something  
   commit  
--------------------------------------------
CREATE PROC A 
   @j int ,
   @c varchar(50),
   @b int
     as
       begin tran
        exec C @c   /*---call procedure C*/
        exec B @b   /*---call procedure B*/
       commit
```

is that  effecting in performance because i declared the same variable more than one time?? but i need to be sure that C and B both of them executed correctly or not ???

Comment: why not use 1 stored procedure?

Comment: because sometime i need to do the tasks of B or C separably and if i used one stored procedure it will be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to encapsulate three stored procedure in `transaction object`

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188929.aspx

Comment: i put them in transaction but the problem was  declared the parameter twice like "@b" one in procedure "A" and one in procedure "B" if i have 100 parameter i will declare them 200 time ?? is that effecting in performance  ??? and if i made "A" do the tasks of "C" and "B" then "A" will be very hard to maintenance so i divide it